# KeyListener doesn't listen

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have the following code. I need to print a message when I press the right arrow. But when I press `VK_RIGHT` the key listener doesn't trigger. It doesn't print the message it is supposed to print. Any ideas why?

```
public class AutoClicker implements KeyListener{

       public static int rate = 0;
       static boolean  keep = true;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       AutoClicker clicker = new AutoClicker();
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setSize(new Dimension(200,300));
       frame.setVisible(true);

       frame.setFocusable(true);
       frame.requestFocus();
   }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
;
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            keep = false;
            System.out.println(keep);

            //System.out.println("Right key typed");
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            System.out.println("Left key typed");
        }

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you searched the forum at all? For example did you look under the "Related" section on the right hand of the page for other questions on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you shouldn't use `KeyListeners` for Swing applications. Please take a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Now to your main problem:

You didn't add a `KeyListener` to the frame, that's why it doesn't work. So add `frame.addKeyListener(this);` (or ideally to the panel you want to have the key listener) and it will work - However you can't make this in a static context, so I would suggest creating the frame inside the constructor. (and calling `new AutoClicker()` **only** in the main method). You can also use the solution in the other answer, but I just prefer it this way :P

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class AutoClicker implements KeyListener {

    public static int rate = 0;
    static boolean keep = true;

    public AutoClicker() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.addKeyListener(this);
        frame.requestFocus();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new AutoClicker();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    };

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            keep = false;
            System.out.println(keep);

            System.out.println("Right key typed");
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            System.out.println("Left key typed");
        }

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To
        // change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Comment: *"First of all, you shouldn't use `KeyListeners` for Swing applications."*  I don't need to read any further before up-voting that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add keylistener to your frame. Just update your main method according to following code.

```
   AutoClicker clicker = new AutoClicker();
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   frame.addKeyListener(clicker);
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setSize(new Dimension(200,300));
   frame.setVisible(true);

   frame.setFocusable(true);
   frame.requestFocus();
```